# Prevent page scroll when data changes in nested scroll in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have a fixed-sized element in a page with "overflow: scroll" which content is changes often.
I expect that changes happened inside this element can affect scroll of this element, but not a page scroll.

But when this element on the top of the page, the page itself begin scroll. How can I prevent this?

To reproduce this behaviour (I've got this problem in chrome, but Firefox works fine):

1. open https://jsfiddle.net/hd2Ltmu0/2/
2. begin to scroll a page to the center of gray element
3. wait a bit and page scroll will move up

Code example:

```
<body>
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll;height: 300px">
        Content that changes often
    </div>
    Content that should not move even the upper block is changed
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

one hacky solution is to store the value of the scroll before adding content and use it after:

```js
setInterval(function() {
 var s= $(window).scrollTop();
 $('.scrollable').children().first().remove();
 $('.scrollable').append('<div>'+(Date.now())+'</div>');
 $(window).scrollTop(s);
}, 1000);

;
```

```css
.demo {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.scrollable {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo">
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
</div>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
  String<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you **remove** element from the DOM  - and then adding new - so that you change the height of the elemnt for a second, the page is scroll.

you should **replace** the element instead removing it.

for example - and this is not logically what you have intended:

```
setInterval(function() {
 $('.scrollable').children().first().replaceWith('<div>'+(Date.now())+'</div>');
}, 1000);
```

will just change element without changing the height or window.offset

Comment: but why changing the content of an element make the page to scroll since that element has a fixed height? (note that it only happen on chrome)

Comment: Yes, in this demo I can make it with reusing existing DOM elements. But in real app I can not because of animation

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by adding an empty div with width of 1px. It's seems that chrome find the first element from the top and move scroll relative to this element. But my solution is pretty hacky and I can't find description of this behaviour in any specs.

```
<body>
    <div style="height: 300px; opacity: 0; width: 1px; float: left;">
    </div>
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll;height: 300px">
        Content that changes often
    </div>
    Content that should not move even the upper block is changed
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y3vtued6/