# Nested elements with `position:fixed` do not respect scrollbars properly in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When having 2 fixed elements. The outer element's scrollbar is over the inner elements content.

[image: Link to image of issue]

This only happens in chrome. I'm pretty sure it's a bug but can you guys think of any kind of fix or work around?

**Example code:**

```css
.divWithScrollbar {
  width: 198px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}

.innerFixedDiv {
  top: 44px;
  left: 131px;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="divWithScrollbar">
  <div class="innerFixedDiv">why does this text go under the scroll bar</div>
  <div style="height: 500px;">this div just creates a scrollbar</div>
</div>
```

**Code in a fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/x90a6q3g/3/

Comment: what is happening with Google chrome and the scroll today: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55833270/8620333 :) ?

Comment: Try to change  position: fixed; to  position: relative; I think its help You.

Comment: @DellDilshod that would help but having fixed is a requirement for proper layout

Comment: I see you removed the accepted answer, it's no more working for you?

Comment: It actually never worked correctly in my scenario unfortunately. Here is the bug on chrome to fix it properly: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=956203&can=2&q=position%20fixed&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&sort=-modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by the chromium team, turned out it was a browser issue.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=956203&can=2&q=position%20fixed&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&sort=-modified

Answer (score 0):

Adding an extra wrapper seems to fix the issue:

```css
.divWithScrollbar {
  width: 198px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: fixed;
}
.wrapper {
  height:100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.innerFixedDiv {
  top: 44px;
  left: 131px;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="divWithScrollbar">
  <div class="innerFixedDiv">I am not more under the scroll bar!</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div style="height: 500px;">this div just creates a scrollbar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```